# Rotate SKSpriteNode on right edge of node instead of in center

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have been searching for this answer and people are saying that using an anchor point is my solution. When I change the anchor point it doesn't work.

I am using SKSpriteKit to make objects move. I have a node that is a body and another node that is an arm. I am trying to rotate the arm in such a matter that its attached to the body but still rotates. What I get is the arm rotating by its center. I would like it to rotate at the edge so it appears attached to the body. Can someone please help? Code snippet below.

```
arm.position = CGPoint(x: -30, y: 0)
arm.zPosition = 1
body.zPosition = 0

addChild(arm)
addChild(body)

var rotation = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi/2.2), duration: 0.4)
var rotationAction = SKAction.sequence([rotation])

arm.run(rotationAction)
```

If I set the anchor point to something like (0.3, 0.5) the arm is still not attached to the body or the position is not where I want it. I would like to know if there is some way to change the sprite's axis of rotation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bendable arm rotation in SpriteKit - rotate at point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294892/bendable-arm-rotation-in-spritekit-rotate-at-point)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51294892/1430420

Comment: Do you understand how anchorPoint works?  It is essentially a push pin into your arm.  So if this was all cardboard cutouts,  it would be the location where you push the pin into the arm, and that pin is where the position is on the body.

Comment: Ok so I put the anchor point to 0.5, 0.5 which is the default, if I change either coordinate value then the arm moves off the body, this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

set `arm.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)`

Comment: This just moves the arm off of the body completely.